# What characters are valid in DAML party names?

Tags: daml

I noticed that Navigator doesn't handle correctly party names that contain spaces. So I was wondering what other characters are illegal and where in the stack (Navigator, DAML-LF, etc.) the limitations apply. I couldn't find anything on this in the documentation. Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something on this in the [docs on the built-in primitive types](https://docs.daml.com/daml/reference/data-types.html#table-of-built-in-primitive-types), under `Party`:

> The party text can only contain alphanumeric characters, `-`, `_` and spaces.